# How to code ajax, php and js in same .js file and retrieve data from database?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax

I want to know whether I can retrieve data from database in .js file using php code written in same .js file. I have a passwordvalidation.js file. In that file, by using onblur event or onclick event, I want to compare the password values with the stored value in password. Now I have password verification code in php and I can compare passwords using that function. But I want to compare it while user entering new password in field. And I want to write ajax and php code in same .js file. But I don't know how to achieve that. Please help on this. Thank you.

Comment: PHP code cannot be written in .JS file. Are you really a programmer?

Comment: Use php to interact with the database, use js to perform the request.

Comment: Besides, you can never rely on any validation done client-side (password checking included).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use jquery

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'test.php',
  success: function(data) {
  $('.result').html(data);
 }
```

});

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use any value which is assigned to any PHP variable, use a hidden input type, set php variable in it and call the value from js function

```
<input type="hidden" id="my_value" value="<?php echo $myvar; ?>" />
```

In js function

```
var phpval = document.getElementById("my_value").value;
```

Now you can retrive the PHP variable value inside JS function ( var phpval)